# Using the GetMediaLibrary() method in python-wordpress-xmlrpc.media, how to iterate over the result?

Tags: attachments, media, xml-rpc

I accessed my Wordpress site's media library using the GetMediaLibrary() method of the python-wordpress-xmlrpc.media module. According to the [documentation](http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/methods.html#module-wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.media), this action should return a list of WordPressMedia instances. However, when I try to iterate over this list using a for-loop, I receive the error:

```
'GetMediaLibrary' object is not iterable
```

This is my code:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import media, posts

client = Client([*redacted*])
allwp_media = media.GetMediaLibrary([])

for media_file in allwp_media:
      if media_file.title == item.filename:
              attachment_url = media_file.link
```

Where 'item.filename' is a string. My Python/coding knowledge is kind of weak, so perhaps there is something fundamental about objects in Python that I do not understand, but I would assume that I should be able to iterate over this list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over media you must first call to WP using your client:

```
allwp_media = client.call(media.GetMediaLibrary())
```